# Python 3: как передать данные из одной функции в другую с последующим возвратом результата?

Tags: python, функции, python-3.x

Добрый день.
Подскажите, как из одной функции вызвать другую, обработать в ней что нужно и вернуть в первоначальную функцию результат?

Есть 2 функции:

## 1

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def prepare(url):
    url = requests.get(url)

    tree = fromstring(url.text)
    tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
    return tree
```

## 2

```
def basic_cinemas_info(url):
    """Receiving Cinema's City, Name and Detailed URL"""

    tree = prepare(url) #Я предполагаю, что в этой части нужно обратиться к функции prepare, но у меня эррорит. Не знаю как правильно написать код на обработку данных в другой функции с последующим возвратом результата сюда же для последующего распарсивания.

    for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
        for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
            city = city.xpath("text()")[0]
            name = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
            detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
        return detailed_url
```

Как правильно из:

`def basic_cinemas_info(url)` передать URL в `def prepare(url)`

и вернуть результат `TREE` из `prepare(url)` в `basic_cinemas_info(url)`?

Comment: Постарайтесь задать конкретные вопросы, ибо читать эту кучу текста, вникать и обрабатывать мне, честно говоря, лень, думаю я не одинок.

Comment: @TheDoctor, таки думаю что вы правы, чуть перестарался. Упростил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде разобрался,

```
    как def prepare(url): отправляет инфо на обработку в def basic_cinemas_info(url):
    и как из def basic_cinemas_info(url): возвращается ответ в def prepare(url):
```

Подробно указано в комментарии в коде + небольшие правки самого кода, так как эррорило.

=========================================================================

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def prepare(url):
    url = requests.get(url)

    tree = fromstring(url.text)
    tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
    return tree

def basic_cinemas_info(url):
    """Receiving Cinema's City, Name and Detailed URL"""

    # вызываем функцию prepare и передаем ей URL (см. последнюю строку), 
    # и результат из функции prepare присваиваем переменной tree
    tree = prepare(url) 

    for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
        for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
            city1 = city.xpath("text()")[0]
            name1 = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
            detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
            print (detailed_url)

basic_cinemas_info('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!=') #Вызываем функцию
```