# Как перенести данные переменной из одной функции в другую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Пишу бота, пытаюсь сделать что то на подобии мафии, но мне нужно перенести данные переменной из одной функции в другую, если что, принты я вписал чтобы в консоли чекать что выдаёт код, код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["rand"])
def rand_user(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    play = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Играть!", callback_data="play")
    markup.add(play)
    mess = 'Для того чтобы начать играть, нажмите на кнопку:)'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup=markup)
    user_list = users_playing
    t = 60
    while t > 0:
        t -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(t)
    if t == 0:
        print(user_list)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def users_playing(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "play":
            list_play = []
            user_name = call.message.from_user.username
            list_play.append(user_name)
            print(list_play)
```

Необходимо, чтобы данные переменной list_play передавались из функции users_playing в функцию rand_user

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3: как передать данные из одной функции в другую с последующим возвратом результата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431410/python-3-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
def exempl1():
    a1 = "I'm sorry"
    return a1

def exempl2():
    d1 = 'Это переменная "a1" из exempl1() - ' + exempl1()
    return d1

print(exempl2())
```

Если надо передать несколько переменных то можете в первой функции сложить их в словарь, а во второй функции принимать словарь и обращаться к нужному элементу словаря.